# AutodeskForge AxiosError: Request failed with status code 400

Tags: autodesk-forge

I am following the Autodesk Forge Simple viewer tutorial and I am getting an error "AxiosError: Request failed with status code 400". any ideas on how to fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sound like you opened the index.html without starting the web server.

1. Open the vscode terminal
2. type `npm install` and press enter.
3. after the package installation is completed and successfully, type `npm start` and press enter.
4. open http://localhost:3000 from your web browser.

Here is the tutorial: https://learnforge.autodesk.io/#/environment/setup/nodejs_2legged